# Cakephp Security component Forcessl conflicts with RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm using security component forcessl to force https throughout the website.

For https: //www.domain.com/pages/detail/terms, In .htaccess file, I'm rewriting rule as follows

```
RewriteRule ^(terms)$ pages/detail/$1/ [L]
```

So it should redirect to https: //www.domain.com/terms.

When terms page is accessed with https: //domain.com/terms it is redirecting to https://www.domain.com/terms.

When terms page is accessed with http://domain.com/terms it is redirecting to https: //www.domain.com/pages/detail/terms.

This is because of the forcessl in controller :

```
$this->redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $this->here); 
$this->here
```

pointing to the original page (pages/detail/terms).  How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Cake PHP's routing function instead? In `config/routes.php` add the following:

```
Router::connect(
    '/terms',
    array(
        'controller' => 'pages',
        'action' => 'detail',
        'terms'
    )
);
```

Comment: No, I tried now and no luck. Forcessl function redirects the current request to https and url turns to domain.com/pages/detail/terms.